# Wake-up PC from sleep mode using PIC24FJ256GB106

Tags: pic

I am trying to wake-up the PC from sleep mode, using PIC24FJ256GB106.

I am using Windows 7. I have installed "Microchip Solutions v2012-04-03" and I used the firmware from "Device - HID - Custom Demos" directory as a starting point.

When I connect my USB device, it shows up in Device Manager, in "Human Interface Devices" tree. (I am using Windows 7) But there is no "Power Management" tab from which I can check the "Allow this device to wake the computer".

Anyways, I figured out some kind of a solution for my device to wake up the computer from sleep. So I have to:

- connect a USB mouse on the same root hub with the device
- I have to check the "Allow this device to wake up the computer" for the mouse
- and in the USBCBSendResume() function, I had to remove the `if(USBGetRemoteWakeupStatus() == TRUE)` condition

How can I wake-up the PC only using the device, without the mouse connected on the same root hub?

Comment: While I see your working the embedded side of this, but I think you might find more useful answers from those on the host side. Maybe repost/move to SO? Good question though!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to alter the config descriptor to enable the device to wake the PC from sleep. Specifically this means setting bit 5 in the **bmAttributes** byte. Have a look through the Microchip USB stack (e.g. config_desc.c or whatever it's named currently), there are plenty of comments to guide you.

[image: Config Descriptor]

> **wTotalLengthequals** the number of bytes in the configuration descriptor and
>   all of its subordinate descriptors.
>   **bNumInterfacesequals** the number of interfaces in the configuration. The
>   minimum is 01h.
>   **bConfigurationValue** identifies the configuration for Get Configuration and
>   Set Configuration requests and must be 01h or higher. A Set Configuration
>   request with a value of zero causes the device to enter the Not Configured state.
>   **iConfiguration** is an index to a string that describes the configuration. This
>   value is zero if there is no string descriptor.
>   **bmAttributes** sets bit 6 = 1 if the device is self-powered and zero if bus pow-ered. Bit 5 = 1 if the device supports the remote wakeup feature, which enables
>   a suspended USB device to tell the host that the device wants to communicate.
>   The other bits in the field are unused. Bits 4..0 must be zero. Bit 7 must equal 1
>   for compatibility with USB 1.0
>   **bMaxPower**.Specifies how much bus current a device requires. For USB 2.0,
>   bMaxPower is in units of 2 mA. If the device requires 200 mA, bMax-Power=64h. For SuperSpeed, bMaxPower is in units of 8 mA.

Above table and info from "USB Complete" by Jan Axelson - an excellent book on all things USB.